# GREP only xyz.log not xyz.log1

Tags: grep

I have a listing of files that have numeric characters at the end after a dot.

ex :

```
abc.log
abc.log.1
xyz.log
xyz.log.1
xyz.log.2
```

I need to list only the logs that have .log at the ending and not the ones with .log.1 or .log.2 at the ending.

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: "I need to list only the logs..." "GREP only xyz.log not xyz.log1"
Are you asking how to grep them or how to list them?
`# grep searchterm *.log` or `# ls *.log` would do this? Or are you asking something else that I'm not understanding?

Comment: I think it's a listing in a file, otherwise the Q doesn't make sense ...

Comment: @pLumo oh yeah, I think you're right. I read his question as asking how to perform a simple grep or ls in a log directory. Yours makes more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$` for end of line :

```
grep '\.log$'
```